# Concerning a polynomial $f\in k[x,y]$ is not divisible by any non-constant polynomial of $k[x]$ nor of $k[y]$

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, field-theory, principal-ideal-domains, unique-factorization-domains

Let $k$ be a field , $f\in k[x,y]$ such that $f$ is not divisible by any non-constant polynomial  of $k[x]$ nor any non-constant polynomial of $k[y]$ . Then is it true that $f$ viewed in $k(x)[y]$ is irreducible iff $f$ viewed in $k(y)[x]$ is irreducible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If $f$ is not divisible by any non-constant polynomial of $k[x]$ nor of $k[y]$, then it is "primitive" viewed in $k[x][y]$ and $k[y][x]$ respectively. Since $k[t]$ is a UFD, you can apply Gauss' Lemma two times and get

$f$ is irreducible in $k(y)[x] \Leftrightarrow$ $f$ is irreducible in $k[y][x]=k[x][y]\Leftrightarrow$ $f$ is irreducible in $k(x)[y]$.